# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include()  While implementing Drupal 6 Multistep Form Using Chaos Tools

Tags: 6, chaos-tool-suite, forms

I would like to implement a multi-step user registration form. After a long time googling, I found [Intro to Drupal 6 Multistep Form Domination Using Chaos Tools](http://www.nicklewis.org/using-chaos-tools-form-wizard-build-multistep-forms-drupal-6). While I was trying to implement the suggested code, I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ctools_include() in var/www/WC/drupal_website/sites/all/modules/wombat/wombat/wombat.module on line 26

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Chaos tools suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module defines `ctools_include()` in [ctools.module](http://drupalcode.org/project/ctools.git/blob_plain/28aba335c4c56ea589110cf1430ddef54f43bc4f:/ctools.module), the only reason I can think of what would explain the error is that you didn't install the module. The other reason could be that you are trying to access the function when the module is still not loaded; for example, if you call the function inside `hook_boot()`, then you would get that error.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am confused with CCK and Ctools nodule, I wrongly enabled the CCK module and test it. Now I enabled the Ctools module and it is works fine. Thank you **kiamlaluno**